# How to produce Log[x,a]+Log[y,b] from Thread[(x + y)~Log~(a + b), Plus]?

Tags: list-manipulation

The following code snippet

```
Thread[(x + y)~Log~(a + b), Plus]
```

produces

`Log[a+b]/Log[x+y]` rather than my expected result `Log[x,a]+Log[y,b]`.

Could you tell me what is wrong in my understanding  here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got the answer.

```
Thread[(x + y)~Hold[Log]~(a + b), Plus] // ReleaseHold
```

Answer (score 2):

First, `Thread` is meant to work on a particular head (lists by default), and you don't have any lists here. Lists are denoted by curly braces `{a, b, c, d}`.

Second, I think you actually want `Apply` (`@@`) here instead. Thread tries to take each element of a list and apply a function to that element, but `Plus` needs at least 2 elements. `Apply` will replace `List` with `Plus`, so `Plus@@List[1, 2, 3, 4]` becomes `Plus[1, 2, 3, 4]` which yields 10.

Therefore, I would use:

```
Plus @@ {x, y}~Log~{a, b}
```

which gives

$\frac{\log(a)}{\log(x)} + \frac{\log(b)}{\log(y)}$

If you really wanted to use `Thread` somehow, you could try this:

```
Plus @@ Thread[Log[{x, y}, {a, b}]]
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

We can look at the difference between these two:

```
(x + y)~Log~(a + b) // FullForm

        (* Times[Log[Plus[a,b]],Power[Log[Plus[x,y]],-1]] *)
```

and

```
(x + y)~f~(a + b) // FullForm

        (* f[Plus[x,y],Plus[a,b]] *)
```

In the first one, we have a bunch of complications because `Log` will evaluate its arguments before `Thread` has a chance to act on it. This can be seen in the Possible Issues section of the `Thread` documentation.

In the second one, since `f` is undefined, it doesn't transform its result at all before passing it to `Thread` and you get the result you expected.

Comment: Try changing `Log` to `Something` and you will understand what I mean much better.

Comment: @OnlyTheParanoidSurvive I've added an update to my answer that I think might help to address your comment.